# Test for Content in a downloaded PDF file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, nightwatch.js

Currently I am trying to figure out a way to verify the contents of a PDF file that will be downloaded while my test is being executed. Is there any way that this can be done?

Comment: Yes, I've used [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to do this in the past and it's worked fine. I'll try to look for an example of how I got it to work. Not sure that I still have one around though.

Comment: Thanks, I would greatly appreciate it